# How to select values from last key of multidimensional array Php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to select the values from the last key array.

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [01] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 15
            [offset] => 4951
        )

    [02] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 15
            [offset] => 4251
        )

    [03] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 15
            [offset] => 4001
        )
)
```

To get the last key here is my code:

```
end($completed_steps);
$lastKey = key($completed_steps);
```

But how can I get the values of the last key? Like, I want to get `cat_id` and `offset`.

(sorry for late response, here's an additional note, I had to confirm this first from someone.)

**NOTE**: I want to store those values as variables. I think I have the idea now.

Comment: find the length of the array and index - 1 with the sum return you last id

Comment: what is your expected output ? `["cat_id","offset"]` or `["15","4001"]` ? or any other output ?

Answer (score 2):

Result of `end()` **is** the last value in array:

```
$values = end($completed_steps);
print_r($values);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code for fetching the values of the last key in array :-

```
$lastValue = end($completed_steps);
$cat_id = $lastValue['cat_id']);
$offset = $lastValue['offset']);
```